# i am using a reusable modal in react and I tried to render a page inside but it seems there is an overlapping

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I have a reusable modal created in react:

```
interface ModalProps {
  isVisible: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  children: any;
}

const ViewModal = ({ isVisible, onClose, children }: ModalProps) => {
  if (!isVisible) return null;

  const handleClose = (e: any) => {
    if (e.target.id === "wrapper") onClose();
  };
  return (
    <div
      className="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-25 backdrop-blur-sm flex justify-center items-center"
      id="wrapper"
      onClick={handleClose}
    >
      <div className="w-[600px] flex flex-col">
        <button
          className="text-white text-xl place-self-end"
          onClick={() => onClose()}
        >
          X
        </button>
        <div className="bg-white p-2 rounded">{children}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ViewModal;
```

I used this modal so that there can be a pop-up page to be displayed but see ...
I am using it to render this:

```
import React from "react";
import ViewModal from "../../components/modal/ViewMonal";

interface CourseInfo {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  no_of_enrolled: number;
}
function CoursesInfo() {
  return (
    <ViewModal
    isVisible={true}
    onClose={() => {}}
    >
      <div className="w-screen h-screen overflow-hidden">
        <div className="mx-auto max-w-screen-lg px-3 py-10">
          <div className="space-y-3">
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-semibold">
              here is where the title is rendered
            </h1>
            <p className="">here is where the description is rendered</p>

            <ul className="flex gap-4">
              <li className="flex">
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  className="mr-2 w-4 text-gray-500"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-width="2"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    d="M17 20h5v-2a3 3 0 00-5.356-1.857M17 20H7m10 0v-2c0-.656-.126-1.283-.356-1.857M7 20H2v-2a3 3 0 015.356-1.857M7 20v-2c0-.656.126-1.283.356-1.857m0 0a5.002 5.002 0 019.288 0M15 7a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0zm6 3a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0zM7 10a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0z"
                  />
                </svg>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div className="mt-10 bg-white py-2">
            <nav className="flex flex-wrap gap-4">
              <a
                href="#"
                className="inline-flex whitespace-nowrap border-b-2 border-transparent py-2 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-600 transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out hover:border-b-purple-600 hover:text-purple-600"
              >
                {" "}
                Announcements{" "}
              </a>

              <a
                href="#"
                className="inline-flex whitespace-nowrap border-b-2 border-transparent border-b-purple-600 py-2 px-3 text-sm font-semibold text-purple-600 transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out"
              >
                {" "}
                Curriculum{" "}
              </a>

              <a
                href="#"
                className="inline-flex whitespace-nowrap border-b-2 border-transparent py-2 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-600 transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out hover:border-b-purple-600 hover:text-purple-600"
              >
                {" "}
                Roster{" "}
              </a>
            </nav>
          </div>

          <ul className="mt-2 space-y-4">
            <li className="text-left">
              <label
                htmlFor="accordion-1"
                className="relative flex flex-col rounded-md border border-gray-100 shadow-md"
              >
                <input
                  className="peer hidden"
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="accordion-1"
                  checked
                />
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  className="absolute right-0 top-4 ml-auto mr-5 h-4 text-gray-500 transition peer-checked:rotate-180"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-width="2"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
                  />
                </svg>
                <div className="relative ml-4 cursor-pointer select-none items-center py-4 pr-2">
                  <h3 className="text-base font-bold text-gray-600 lg:text-base">
                    What are material
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div className="max-h-0 overflow-hidden transition-all duration-500 peer-checked:max-h-96">
                  <ul className="space-y-1 font-semibold text-gray-600 mb-6">
                    <li className="flex px-2 sm:px-6 py-2.5 hover:bg-gray-100">
                      <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        className="mr-2 w-6"
                      >
                        <path
                          fill-rule="evenodd"
                          d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM9.555 7.168A1 1 0 008 8v4a1 1 0 001.555.832l3-2a1 1 0 000-1.664l-3-2z"
                          clip-rule="evenodd"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                      Something to Ponder{" "}
                      <span className="ml-auto text-sm"> 23 min </span>
                    </li>
                    <li className="flex px-2 sm:px-6 py-2.5 hover:bg-gray-100">
                      <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        className="mr-2 w-6"
                      >
                        <path
                          fill-rule="evenodd"
                          d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM9.555 7.168A1 1 0 008 8v4a1 1 0 001.555.832l3-2a1 1 0 000-1.664l-3-2z"
                          clip-rule="evenodd"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                      Tables <span className="ml-auto text-sm"> 23 min </span>
                    </li>
                    <li className="flex px-2 sm:px-6 py-2.5 hover:bg-gray-100">
                      <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        className="mr-2 w-6"
                      >
                        <path
                          fill-rule="evenodd"
                          d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM9.555 7.168A1 1 0 008 8v4a1 1 0 001.555.832l3-2a1 1 0 000-1.664l-3-2z"
                          clip-rule="evenodd"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                      HTML Entities{" "}
                      <span className="ml-auto text-sm"> 23 min </span>
                    </li>
                    <li className="flex px-2 sm:px-6 py-2.5 hover:bg-gray-100">
                      <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        className="mr-2 w-6"
                      >
                        <path
                          fill-rule="evenodd"
                          d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM9.555 7.168A1 1 0 008 8v4a1 1 0 001.555.832l3-2a1 1 0 000-1.664l-3-2z"
                          clip-rule="evenodd"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                      HTML Iframes{" "}
                      <a
                        href="#trailer-modal"
                        className="ml-2 rounded-full border bg-purple-100 px-2 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-purple-500"
                        uk-toggle=""
                      >
                        {" "}
                        Preview{" "}
                      </a>
                      <span className="ml-auto text-sm"> 23 min </span>
                    </li>
                    <li className="flex px-2 sm:px-6 py-2.5 hover:bg-gray-100">
                      <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        className="mr-2 w-6"
                      >
                        <path
                          fill-rule="evenodd"
                          d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM9.555 7.168A1 1 0 008 8v4a1 1 0 001.555.832l3-2a1 1 0 000-1.664l-3-2z"
                          clip-rule="evenodd"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                      Some important things
                      <span className="ml-auto text-sm"> 23 min </span>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li className="text-left">
              <label
                htmlFor="accordion-2"
                className="relative flex flex-col rounded-md border border-gray-100 shadow-md"
              >
                <input
                  className="peer hidden"
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="accordion-2"
                />
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  className="absolute right-0 top-4 ml-auto mr-5 h-4 text-gray-500 transition peer-checked:rotate-180"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-width="2"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
                  />
                </svg>
                <div className="relative ml-4 cursor-pointer select-none items-center py-4 pr-2">
                  <h3 className="text-base font-bold text-gray-600 lg:text-base">
                    Outcomes
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div className="max-h-0 overflow-hidden transition-all duration-500 peer-checked:max-h-96">
                  <ul className="space-y-1 font-semibold text-gray-600 mb-6"></ul>
                </div>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li className="text-left">
              <label
                htmlFor="accordion-3"
                className="relative flex flex-col rounded-md border border-gray-100 shadow-md"
              >
                <input
                  className="peer hidden"
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="accordion-3"
                />
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  className="absolute right-0 top-4 ml-auto mr-5 h-4 text-gray-500 transition peer-checked:rotate-180"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-width="2"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
                  />
                </svg>
                <div className="relative ml-4 cursor-pointer select-none items-center py-4 pr-2">
                  <h3 className="text-base font-bold text-gray-600 lg:text-base">
                    Resources
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div className="max-h-0 overflow-hidden transition-all duration-500 peer-checked:max-h-96">
                  <ul className="space-y-1 font-semibold text-gray-600 mb-6"></ul>
                </div>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li className="text-left">
              <label
                htmlFor="accordion-4"
                className="relative flex flex-col rounded-md border border-gray-100 shadow-md"
              >
                <input
                  className="peer hidden"
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="accordion-4"
                />
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  className="absolute right-0 top-4 ml-auto mr-5 h-4 text-gray-500 transition peer-checked:rotate-180"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-width="2"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
                  />
                </svg>
              </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ViewModal>
  );
}

export default CoursesInfo;
```

but seems there is an overlapping here:
[image]

It should somehow be displayed like this:
[image]

but the difference is that I am trying to make it a pop up

I tried many ways but couldn't solve the problem. I hope someone helps me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the `div` that has `w-screen` which is equal to `width: 100vw;`, thus, causing the overlapping issue.

you could replace it with `w-full` and then pass `w-screen` to the modal through a `prop` then either set the modal width to `w-[600px]` or to the passed `prop` (e.g. `modalWidth`).

```
interface ModalProps {
  isVisible: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  children: any;
  modalWidth: string
}

const ViewModal = ({ isVisible, onClose, children, modalWidth }: ModalProps) => {
  if (!isVisible) return null;

  const handleClose = (e) => {
    if (e.target.id === "wrapper") onClose();
  };
  return (
    <div
      className="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-25 backdrop-blur-sm flex justify-center items-center"
      id="wrapper"
      onClick={handleClose}
    >
      <div className={`${modalWidth || "w-[600px]"} flex flex-col`}>
        <button
          className="text-white text-xl place-self-end"
          onClick={() => onClose()}
        >
          X
        </button>
        <div className="bg-white p-2 rounded">{children}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export function CoursesInfo() {
  return (
    <ViewModal isVisible={true} modalWidth="w-screen" onClose={() => {}}>
      <div className="h-screen overflow-hidden">
        <div className="mx-auto max-w-screen-lg px-3 py-10">
          <div className="space-y-3">
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-semibold">
              here is where the title is rendered
            </h1>
            <p className="">here is where the description is rendered</p>

            <ul className="flex gap-4">
              <li className="flex">
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  className="mr-2 w-4 text-gray-500"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-width="2"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    d="M17 20h5v-2a3 3 0 00-5.356-1.857M17 20H7m10 0v-2c0-.656-.126-1.283-.356-1.857M7 20H2v-2a3 3 0 015.356-1.857M7 20v-2c0-.656.126-1.283.356-1.857m0 0a5.002 5.002 0 019.288 0M15 7a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0zm6 3a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0zM7 10a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0z"
                  />
                </svg>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div className="mt-10 bg-white py-2">
            <nav className="flex flex-wrap gap-4">
              <a
                href="#"
                className="inline-flex whitespace-nowrap border-b-2 border-transparent py-2 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-600 transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out hover:border-b-purple-600 hover:text-purple-600"
              >
                {" "}
                Announcements{" "}
              </a>

              <a
                href="#"
                className="inline-flex whitespace-nowrap border-b-2 border-transparent border-b-purple-600 py-2 px-3 text-sm font-semibold text-purple-600 transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out"
              >
                {" "}
                Curriculum{" "}
              </a>

              <a
                href="#"
                className="inline-flex whitespace-nowrap border-b-2 border-transparent py-2 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-600 transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out hover:border-b-purple-600 hover:text-purple-600"
              >
                {" "}
                Roster{" "}
              </a>
            </nav>
          </div>

          <ul className="mt-2 space-y-4">
            <li className="text-left">
              <label
                htmlFor="accordion-1"
                className="relative flex flex-col rounded-md border border-gray-100 shadow-md"
              >
                <input
                  className="peer hidden"
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="accordion-1"
                  checked
                />
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  className="absolute right-0 top-4 ml-auto mr-5 h-4 text-gray-500 transition peer-checked:rotate-180"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-width="2"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
                  />
                </svg>
                <div className="relative ml-4 cursor-pointer select-none items-center py-4 pr-2">
                  <h3 className="text-base font-bold text-gray-600 lg:text-base">
                    What are material
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div className="max-h-0 overflow-hidden transition-all duration-500 peer-checked:max-h-96">
                  <ul className="space-y-1 font-semibold text-gray-600 mb-6">
                    <li className="flex px-2 sm:px-6 py-2.5 hover:bg-gray-100">
                      <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        className="mr-2 w-6"
                      >
                        <path
                          fill-rule="evenodd"
                          d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM9.555 7.168A1 1 0 008 8v4a1 1 0 001.555.832l3-2a1 1 0 000-1.664l-3-2z"
                          clip-rule="evenodd"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                      Something to Ponder{" "}
                      <span className="ml-auto text-sm"> 23 min </span>
                    </li>
                    <li className="flex px-2 sm:px-6 py-2.5 hover:bg-gray-100">
                      <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        className="mr-2 w-6"
                      >
                        <path
                          fill-rule="evenodd"
                          d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM9.555 7.168A1 1 0 008 8v4a1 1 0 001.555.832l3-2a1 1 0 000-1.664l-3-2z"
                          clip-rule="evenodd"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                      Tables <span className="ml-auto text-sm"> 23 min </span>
                    </li>
                    <li className="flex px-2 sm:px-6 py-2.5 hover:bg-gray-100">
                      <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        className="mr-2 w-6"
                      >
                        <path
                          fill-rule="evenodd"
                          d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM9.555 7.168A1 1 0 008 8v4a1 1 0 001.555.832l3-2a1 1 0 000-1.664l-3-2z"
                          clip-rule="evenodd"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                      HTML Entities{" "}
                      <span className="ml-auto text-sm"> 23 min </span>
                    </li>
                    <li className="flex px-2 sm:px-6 py-2.5 hover:bg-gray-100">
                      <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        className="mr-2 w-6"
                      >
                        <path
                          fill-rule="evenodd"
                          d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM9.555 7.168A1 1 0 008 8v4a1 1 0 001.555.832l3-2a1 1 0 000-1.664l-3-2z"
                          clip-rule="evenodd"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                      HTML Iframes{" "}
                      <a
                        href="#trailer-modal"
                        className="ml-2 rounded-full border bg-purple-100 px-2 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-purple-500"
                        uk-toggle=""
                      >
                        {" "}
                        Preview{" "}
                      </a>
                      <span className="ml-auto text-sm"> 23 min </span>
                    </li>
                    <li className="flex px-2 sm:px-6 py-2.5 hover:bg-gray-100">
                      <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        className="mr-2 w-6"
                      >
                        <path
                          fill-rule="evenodd"
                          d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM9.555 7.168A1 1 0 008 8v4a1 1 0 001.555.832l3-2a1 1 0 000-1.664l-3-2z"
                          clip-rule="evenodd"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                      Some important things
                      <span className="ml-auto text-sm"> 23 min </span>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li className="text-left">
              <label
                htmlFor="accordion-2"
                className="relative flex flex-col rounded-md border border-gray-100 shadow-md"
              >
                <input
                  className="peer hidden"
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="accordion-2"
                />
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  className="absolute right-0 top-4 ml-auto mr-5 h-4 text-gray-500 transition peer-checked:rotate-180"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-width="2"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
                  />
                </svg>
                <div className="relative ml-4 cursor-pointer select-none items-center py-4 pr-2">
                  <h3 className="text-base font-bold text-gray-600 lg:text-base">
                    Outcomes
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div className="max-h-0 overflow-hidden transition-all duration-500 peer-checked:max-h-96">
                  <ul className="space-y-1 font-semibold text-gray-600 mb-6"></ul>
                </div>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li className="text-left">
              <label
                htmlFor="accordion-3"
                className="relative flex flex-col rounded-md border border-gray-100 shadow-md"
              >
                <input
                  className="peer hidden"
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="accordion-3"
                />
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  className="absolute right-0 top-4 ml-auto mr-5 h-4 text-gray-500 transition peer-checked:rotate-180"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-width="2"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
                  />
                </svg>
                <div className="relative ml-4 cursor-pointer select-none items-center py-4 pr-2">
                  <h3 className="text-base font-bold text-gray-600 lg:text-base">
                    Resources
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div className="max-h-0 overflow-hidden transition-all duration-500 peer-checked:max-h-96">
                  <ul className="space-y-1 font-semibold text-gray-600 mb-6"></ul>
                </div>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li className="text-left">
              <label
                htmlFor="accordion-4"
                className="relative flex flex-col rounded-md border border-gray-100 shadow-md"
              >
                <input
                  className="peer hidden"
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="accordion-4"
                />
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  className="absolute right-0 top-4 ml-auto mr-5 h-4 text-gray-500 transition peer-checked:rotate-180"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-width="2"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
                  />
                </svg>
              </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ViewModal>
  );
}
```

[Check the working demo](https://playcode.io/1803047)